# Magento overriding Mage_Core_Model_Email class

Tags: php, magento, model, content-management-system, overriding

I am trying to extend functionality in the Mage_Core_Model_Email class. 
I would like to override the model, in order to modify the zend_mail call to send attachments with emails.

I am already using outsourceonline captcha extension, to add security text to all my forms, and this is extending the contacts index controller. (Saying, just in case this may be interfering with my code... although I don't think so).

I have defined a new module 'My' and package 'core':

- I created the module xml in app/etc.... and enabled the module, I tested if the module is recognised and active, and it is.
- created local module repo..../local/My/Core  containing 2 folders... Model, and etc.
- created my config.xml to override the email class
- created my new class... extending the old email model class.

config.xml code...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <My_Core>
        <version>0.1.0</version>  
    </My_Core>
</modules>
<global>
        <models>
        <core>
            <rewrite>
                <email>
                    My_Core_Model_Emailwattachments
                </email>
            </rewrite>
        </core>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

And my class declaration...

```
class My_Core_Model_Emailwattachments extends Mage_Core_Model_Email
{
```

I've added a var_dump inside the constructor.

When run my contacts form, and send an email... this class does not get run.
I've tested that the function I'm trying to override in the original class IS run.... but can't get it to accept my class as an alternative.

Tried many combinations of tags inside config.xml, based on examples online.... but it just won't work.

Does anyone see or know what I may be missing? Is there any more tests I can do to see why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to tell Magento that your Module includes models...

```
<models>
    <core>
        <rewrite>
            <email>
                My_Core_Model_Emailwattachments
            </email>
        </rewrite>
    </core>
    <mycore>
        <class>My_Core_Model</class>
    </mycore>
</models>
```

Comment: Hi Cags....thanks for the quick response. I tried the code...but doesnt work still. Im a bit confused with your syntax, as obviously syntx is key here... Where you specified 'mycore' tag. should that be my_core??? and does capitalisation interfere if used in xml tags here?  Tried a few variations based on what i just said, but no koy at the minute.

Comment: It can be any value you like, the example I gave would be the value I'd recommend. It is the namespace that is used by get model, i.e. to create an instance of your model you would do `Mage::getModel('mycore/emailwattachments')`. The <core> node in your example is you adding an element into the config.xml of app/code/core/mage/core/etc/config.xml. So somebody could overload your module by using <mycore><rewrite><emailwattachments>Their_Core_Model... Did you `rm -rf var/cache/mage--* after changing your xml?

Comment: Yes thx. Questioing everything at min...cant see why not working.  :/

I have cache disabled for now to help.
Cant post new code I have...but i cant get it to work. Is there somewhere i can check if the rewrite IS in place on the system?  a data entry somewhere?   This may help me narrow down the problem.

Im also thinking that maybe my outsourceonline_captcha might be in the way....but doesnt override the email.php model....so surely not.
Very odd...